# python.exe not ending when it is started with a .bat script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, wxpython

I have a simple Python program with wxPython GUI and a taskbar icon. I essentially start the program with the following .bat script:

```
cd %~dp0
.\components\window.py
```

To end the program, the user simply selects the exit option from the custom taskbar icon.

```
def onClickExit(self, event):
    app.keepGoing = False
    self.frame.Destroy()
    self.Destroy()
```

What I am finding is that the when I close the window with this method, the command line window that was opened by the running of this script remains open. Is there a way for me to terminate the window when I am destroying the wxPython frame and taskbar icon? This appears to be an issue with when a .py script is run via a .bat script.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues when using a `wx.TaskBarIcon`. The wx.TaskBarIcon instance has to be destroyed BEFORE you call the frame's Destroy() method. This is what I usually do in my close method:

```
self.tbIcon.RemoveIcon()
self.tbIcon.Destroy()
self.Destroy()
```

You should check out this tutorial as it might help you too:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-how-to-minimize-to-system-tray/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def onClickExit(self, event):
    exit()
```

Do you have multiple frames defined? The command line will only close, if every frame is 'Destroyed'.
With the `exit()` command the script will be terminated completely.

Hope it helped! :)

Phil